# Hiding Template Dropdown inside Pages from Specific Admin User ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to restrict my client with the #id of 10 so that when they login, and go to a page in the backend of Wordpress, they would not be able to change the [Template Dropdown](https://icowebsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/wordpress-custom-page-template-not-displaying-in-dropdown.png)

It's probably something to add in the `functions.php`  right?

Has anyone had any luck doing this?

Would like to make it so I can see it as one admin user, but since they are another admin user, it'd need to define it to hide by their user id

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. I've tested and it's working fine from my side.

```
function custom_remove_page_template() {
global $pagenow;

$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); // Get user ID function
if ($user_ID == 10 || $user_ID == 11) { // You can add multiple user id here
    if ( in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post-new.php', 'post.php') ) && get_post_type() == 'page' ) { 
        ?>
        <script>
            (function($){
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#page_template option[value="sidebar-page.php"]').remove();
                })
            })(jQuery)
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
}
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_remove_page_template', 10);
```

Comment: Just tried it (used ID 10 which is the user i want to hide TEMPLATES from) and it didn't work.  Also, is there a way to hide Templates drop down, the PERMALINKS field as well as the PAGE ATTRIBUTES fin addition to the TEMPLATE drop down? I've had clients go into WP and make too many changes and change things by mistake so trying to avoid this

Comment: Can you please share your code so I can check